# WinForms UI validation using attributes as in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

In ASP.NET MVC, we can decorate our properties with validation attributes. Then, this validation is applied at the presentation layer (views, client side) and controller and data access alike.

My question is -can we accomplish this somehow in WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the windows forms world, you would use [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx), specifically the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41e17s4b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) interfaces and related classes.